# Confusion about product of change of basis matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I am asked to prove the following on an exercise sheet:

> If $V$ has dimension $n$, then change of basis can be thought of as a linear map $F^n \to F^n$, sending the old coordinates to the new ones. Now let $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_3$ be three bases of a vector space $V$ over a field $F$. Let $M_1$ be the change of basis matrix from $B_1$ to $B_2$, and let $M_2$ be the change of basis matrix from $B_2$ to $B_3$. Show that the change of basis matrix from $B_1$ to $B_3$ is $M_2 M_1$.

But here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_Change_of_Basis_Matrices it says that $$\mathbf M_{\mathcal A,\mathcal C} = \mathbf M_{\mathcal A,\mathcal B} \cdot \mathbf M_{\mathcal B,\mathcal C}$$
where the change of basis matrix from $A$ to $B$ is the matrix whose columns are the coordinate vectors of the elements of the new basis $\left \langle {b_n} \right \rangle$ relative to the original basis $\left \langle {a_n} \right \rangle$.

Letting $\mathcal A = B_1$, $\mathcal B = B_2$ and $\mathcal C = B_3$, would this not suggest that the correct matrix is $M_1 M_2$ not $M_2 M_1$?